# send email of any domain through aspx page

Tags: c#

```
    string from = txtEmail.Text;

    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text, "xyz@gmail.com"))
    {
        mm.Subject = "zaca";
        mm.Body = " vfsdfs ";
        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
    }
```

im using this code to send mail through my web page. but it can send mail to the admin through a gmail account only. i want that a user of any email service could send mail through my webpage. please help.

Comment: So is this user *your* user? i.e. do you essentially want to swap out the credentials with variables? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` should be false if you are sending to gmail it expects a valid username / password based on msdn documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You have specified you SMTP host as `smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";` and it will use GMail servers to send the email.

Comment: yes i am the user. this code is working only to exchange mail between gmail users. i want that a person with any other mail domain like yahoo or reddif or any other could also send mail through this page.